# How to pass a value from underscore.js to the MVC Controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, underscore.js-templating, url.action

Using underscore.js in my View, I'm trying to pass the variable `serialNumberId` back to my view. Here's what I tried:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("process", "wip", new { id = <%= serialNumberId %> })">
    Text
</a>
```

...but it didn't like that. Red squiggles.

Then I tried:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("process", "wip")/<%= serialNumberId %>">
    Text
</a>
```

...but then the code never even reached my `process` action method in the controller.

Everything works fine if I hardcode a serialNumberId value like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("process", "wip", new { id = 10 })">
    Text
</a>
```

or like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("process", "wip")/10">
    Text
</a>
```

So how do I do THAT, but with my `serialNumberId` variable instead?

**Edit:** Here's the code where `serialNumberId` is coming from (it's part of a DataTables function):

```
...
columns: [
    {
        data: 'serialNumberId', searchable: false, orderable: false,
        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            var structure = _.template($('#tmpl-actions').html()),
                html = structure({ serialNumberId: data });

            return html;
        }
    },
```

**Edit 2:** Okay, so after some more playing around, I don't think this is an underscore problem. This is a datatables problem. `serialNumberId: data` above is Null for some reason. When I step through the ASP.Net it's being filled with an int, but by the time it goes through DataTables it's empty.

Comment: Where is this code in conjunction with your javascript code?

Comment: What was the actual output for the second attempt?  What was the URL of the resulting request?

Comment: I added the code where serialNumberId is coming from

Answer (score 0):

if serialNumberId is jquery variable you can't use it with razor syntax.
but if you want create url with it you can do this `

```
<script>               
    $("a").click(function(){
         var url='@Url.Action("process","wip")'+serialNumberId;
         window.location.href=url;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's not a jquery variable, it's coming from some DataTables code that I included just now at the bottom of the original post